# Change tuple inside a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

since tuples are immutable is there a way that given this list:

```
lista = [((0,0), False), ((1,0), False)]
```

I can replace the `(1,0)` by `(2,0)` in order to get:

```
lista = [((0,0), False), ((2,0), False)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is create new tuples and define the element on the list by index:

```
lista[1] = ((2,0), False)
```